# Probability to guess a random number with little feedback

Tags: probability

<sup>I have tried to look for this question for a while, and found some answers that came close, but not quite.</sup>

> I choose a number between $1$ and $N$, and let you guess. All I tell you is whether you are right or wrong. What is the expected number of guesses?

At first, I thought that this is simply a geometric distribution. However, if I let $N=1$ then the required number of guesses is $0$ (I know that the number must be $1$).

Similarly, if $N=2$, then the required number of guesses is always $1$ (if I guess correctly, then I know what the number is, if I guess incorrectly, I know it is the other number).

Can anyone point me in the correct direction as to how to compute this expectation value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mu_n$ be the expected number of guesses if it is a number in $\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Then we have $\mu_1=0$ and for $n>1$ we have the relation:$$\mu_n=\frac1n\cdot1+\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot(1+\mu_{n-1})=1+\frac{n-1}{n}\mu_{n-1}$$

So setting $\alpha_n:=n\mu_n$ we have $\alpha_1=0$ and for $n>1$:$$\alpha_n=n+\alpha_{n-1}$$

Then $\alpha_n=n+(n-1)+\dots+2=\frac12n(n+1)-1$ so that: $$\mu_n=\frac12(n+1)-\frac1{n}$$